# How do you update the timestamps in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models `Job` and `User`.

Users can be assigned many jobs, and jobs can have many assignees.

```
class Job extends Model {

  public function assignees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withTimestamps();
  }

}


class User extends Model {

  public function jobs()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job')->withTimestamps();
  }

}
```

In my Job Controller I am updating the assignees like this:

```
$job = Job::find(1);

$job->assignees()->sync([1,2]);

$job->save();
```

Everything is working as expected except the timestamp of the job is not updating.

The `updated_at` field remains unchanged.

Can anyone see where my problem may be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to the docs, this should do the work:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps

Your models should include a new array attribute `$touches` which gets a new item with the name of the relation.

```php
class Job extends Model {

  //if you also want to update a user model from the jobs site
  protected $touches = ['assignees'];

  public function assignees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withTimestamps();
  }

}


class User extends Model {

  protected $touches = ['jobs'];

  public function jobs()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job')->withTimestamps();
  }

}
```

**BTW:** The `withTimestamps()`-method only updates the timestamps of your intermediate table.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It was driving me crazy. I could have sword it tried that before

Comment: It just came to my mind, that this solution has one drawback. Setting this within your model will cause a ```touch()``` for every query on this relationship except for a select.

Comment: that would be the intention. Any change to that assignments should always touch the job

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$job->touch();` after `$job->assignees()->sync([1,2]);` line like this:

```
$job = Job::find(1);
$job->assignees()->sync([1,2]);
$job->touch();
$job->save();
```

And this will update the timestamps for you.

Comment: Thanks that works. I think I prefer to put the touches property in the Model though